# Issues with Windows batch file ECHO command

Tags: batch-file

I have the following Windows batch file, which gets a list of every `.txt` file in the directory, prints a message, and calls a command to process each file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /r %%F in (.\*.txt) do (
   echo processing %%F 
   && my_comand < "%%F"
)
ENDLOCAL
```

In the main, the batch file works, but there are two small issues.

*First*, instead of just printing

`processing <FILE_NAME>`

this

`processing <FILE_NAME> &` is printed - note the trailing `(`.

*Second*, for the second and subsequent files, the following is written :

```
C:\...\bin>(
echo processing <MY_FILE> &  & my_command   0<<FILE_NAME>
)
processing <FILE_NAME> &
```

In other words, the entire expanded command is output.

I wonder is someone can help point out what is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is a lot easier to use the normal/usual syntax

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /r %%F in (*.txt) do (
    echo processing %%F 
    my_comand < "%%F"
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Anyway, this *should* work

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /r %%F in (*.txt) do ^
echo processing %%F ^
 & my_comand < "%%F"
ENDLOCAL
```

Note the space before the `&`

Comment: Thanks, but, using the nornal/usual syntax, I get similar output - have updated the question.

Comment: I see the issue - the batch file I was calling had set ECHO  ON - adding @echo off before the end of the loop fixes the issue